# Process Builder - Updating related record for Event

Tags: process-builder, event

Event is related to Opportunity in our Org via the polymorphic relationship `(Event.WhatId = Opportunity.Id)`

I have to update a field on opportunity when an update happens on event and I am unable to refer the opportunity (see below..as you can see I do not see any opportunity object at all)
[image]

Is it because the relationship is polymorphic ?

Comment: I think activities are just weird. You might be able to update a related owner, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you managed to find a solution, but it is possible. You need to reference the Account first, then select the related records and filter to the relevant record.

Here's a knowledge article: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iQPmQAM

I've also done this by calling a Flow from the Process Builder and performing the field update in the Flow.

Hope this helps :-)